# Why doesn't this table have a width of 100% in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, colors

I don't understand why this table doesn't span the whole page in Chrome. It works fine in IE. The page is the cart page and it has a table of 5 columns. Is it possible to do this using just CSS?    https://jsfiddle.net/bc10ggc6/

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
<h1>I'm not going to add the code because it's too large and stackoverflow are asking for too much text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: your table is 100% width, but your content is not responsive

Comment: How do I make them responsive?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bc10ggc6/3/)

Your images are ruining your layout.

Add this rule to your images:

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have media queries set but they aren't relevant

Comment: did your try the fiddle?

Comment: dude you cannot expect someone to solve your entire problem. You can ask for a specific thing, and ask as precisely as you can. But you can't say it's not good on mobile when you didn't mention anywhere in your question that you want it on mobile. How would I know that? Think twice when ask a question.

Comment: I asked WHY THIS TABLE DOESN'T HAVE A WIDTH OF 100% IN CHROME. I also mentioned that it does in IE in JSFIFFLE.  I didn't mention there being an issue with the image. Then when you decided to address the issue, I mentioned that there isn't an issue there because I have media queries set for other viewports.